# WSDL for individual operations

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I have received a wsdl from my client to invoke their web services built in WCF. This wsdl have got n number of operations which are not actually necessary for my purpose. Instead, I need only 2-3 methods to be invoked. Is there any possible way for me to split the wsdl or tweak the wsdl to work for only my methods?

Answer (score 0):

Although it may be possible to edit the wsdl and remove the opertaions you don't plan to use, it's probably a lot easier to provide a default implementation. You can use e.g. `throw new NotImplementedException()` as method body. This has the nice side effect of throwing an exception when calling code inadvertently calls a method you didn't plan on using.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to meet your requirement with wsdl.
But you could remove the method you don't want after you have added service reference through this wsdl.

For example, I have ICalculatorService  service contract and CalculatorServiceClient service proxy after I  have added reference.

```
public interface ICalculatorService  {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ICalculatorService/Add", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ICalculatorService/AddResponse")]
    double Add(double a, double b);



    //[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ICalculatorService/Substract", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ICalculatorService/SubstractResponse")]
    //double Substract(double a, double b);

}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface ICalculatorServiceChannel : consoleClient.CalculatorClient.ICalculatorService, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class CalculatorServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<consoleClient.CalculatorClient.ICalculatorService>, consoleClient.CalculatorClient.ICalculatorService {

    public CalculatorServiceClient() {
    }

    public CalculatorServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }

    public CalculatorServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public CalculatorServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public CalculatorServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public double Add(double a, double b) {
        return base.Channel.Add(a, b);
    }



    //public double Substract(double a, double b) {
    //    return base.Channel.Substract(a, b);
    //}


}
```

If I don't want Substract method, I could comment out  the Substract method in both ICalculatorService   and  CalculatorServiceClient.